# Why is the rubber tip of my capacitive stylus no longer conductive?

Tags: polymers, conductivity

In 2014, so eight years ago, I bought five styluses from China. Cheap stuff obviously. They worked fine while I used them, but soon after they were just left in a drawer. Last night I realized that they all don't work anymore. I cant even make a single click on my phone. I also tried with other devices.

The pen, all of it except for the rubber tip, is made from stainless steel.

The tip is made like a small bladder from black rubber. When you press it against a surface, from any angle, it presses against that surface with an are similar to a circle with a 5mm diameter.

The rubber does not appear to be cracked, deteriorated, discolored or anything like that.

From what I can read, the rubber tip is most likely made from so called conductive polymers. Is it normal that these age / deteriorate in such a way, that they lose their conductivity?

My friend suggested, that if it was some kind of conductive carbon / graphite, that might simply "fall of" the rubber as dust.

I am asking out of simple curiosity :)

Comment: Are you still using them with the same device?

Comment: @No: In 2014 I used it with an Acer tablet and a Samsung Galaxy Ace, but I don't have any of those anymore. Yesterday I tested it with two different phone models from Huawei and OnePlus, and a tablet from Apple.

Comment: I cannot imagine what should happen to an unbent rubber in a dark closet (under stress, rubber undergoes ozonolysis and develops cracks). My best guess would be the new phones want a stylus that is somehow different.

Comment: @Karl: I cant totally dismiss that. And unfortunately I dont see a way of finding out. However, my personal experience indicates that newer phones are more sensitive than older ones; for instance my newer smart phones work more reliably with gloves than my first ones did.